# Does the laziness of vendors affect how the rides/shops run?

Tags: rollercoaster-tycoon-3

I was looking through some of the menus and I noticed that vendors have a significantly high laziness.

[image: Staff]

Does this affect how any of the rides or shops run and does training them/giving them discipline do anything to affect the productivity of the rides or shops (like when you train mechanics or janitors)?

Comment: I'm not sure about ride vendors, but shop stalls would take longer to go through customers the lazier they were, but since guests in line just throw money at the vendor then go on the ride, it doesn't seem like they are affected.

Comment: @Rapitor You can go ahead and post an answer anyways, I didn't know that about the shop stalls which answers most of my question. The ride vendor answer makes sense as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - laziness effects the productivity of your staff.

Laziness is reduced through training which in turn increases the productivity of your staff (ie: janitors will actively seek out the nearest mess, entertainers will actively seek out the saddest guest, vendors will process customers faster, etc).